# ArrayBuffer cannot be parsed

Tags: sockets, google-chrome-app, arraybuffer

Reading from a [chrome socket](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket#method-recvFrom) has really become a pain for me.

As many before me, I'm using the following code to convert back and forth between an ArrayBuffer and a string:

```
function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}

function str2ab(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
  var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}
```

Unfortunately, what I receive from the socket seems to be unparsable.

Let's say the datagram is:

```
01,33,2.58,1.00
```

the following code fails poorly:

```
function message(msg, rinfo) {

    var string = ab2str(msg);
    console.log(string);
    var data = string.split(",");
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       data[i] = parseFloat(data[i]);
       console.log(data[i]);
    }
}
```

**Console output:**

```
01,33,2.58,1.00
0
NaN
NaN
NaN
```

Comment: What's on the other end of the connection?

Comment: A client with a `sendTo()` function transmitting an ArrayBuffer converted using the `str2ab()`

Comment: str2ab() -> sendTo() -> recvFrom() -> ab2str()

Comment: So... if I understand your console output well, you received the right msg (01,33,2.58,1.00, as per the first console.log), you are just splitting and printing it wrong, no?

Comment: The split appears it should work fine.. perhaps there are non-printing characters in the string.  Can you check `string.length` to confirm its what you expect?  Or inspect the raw char values with `Array.prototype.map.call(string, function(c) { return c.charCodeAt(0); })`

Comment: For what it's worth, the code in the original question works for me on 36.0.1941.2. The test I used was "var ab = str2ab('01,33,2.58,1.00'); message(ab);" and I got back the four floats correctly parsed.

Answer (score 1):

I, too, have found that that code doesn't work, even though it has been offered as a solution in one or more Stack Overflow "solutions." Instead, I use code taken from the Google Chrome App tcpserver example:

```
/**
* Converts an array buffer to a string
*
* @private
* @param {ArrayBuffer} buf The buffer to convert
* @param {Function} callback The function to call when conversion is complete
*/
function _arrayBufferToString(buf, callback) {
    var bb = new Blob([new Uint8Array(buf)]);
    var f = new FileReader();
    f.onload = function(e) {
        callback(e.target.result);
    };
    f.readAsText(bb);
}

/**
* Converts a string to an array buffer
*
* @private
* @param {String} str The string to convert
* @param {Function} callback The function to call when conversion is complete
*/
function _stringToArrayBuffer(str, callback) {
    var bb = new Blob([str]);
    var f = new FileReader();
    f.onload = function(e) {
        callback(e.target.result);
    };
    f.readAsArrayBuffer(bb);
}
```

Comment: No sync version in any of the official Google example code, to my knowledge, and I'd be very surprised if there were, as asynchronous is the name of the game when you're writing Chrome Apps.